# getActionView() always returning null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-edittext

I am trying to add an EditText to my action bar. However when I try to search for the item using getActionView() it always returns null.

I just spent some 5 hours searching the web for a solution but all what I found relates to SearchView which does not apply to my case.

It seems that I need to use the MenuItemCompat.getActionView() because my minSDK is 8, but it always returns null.

Another solution suggested changing the proguard rules but that did not help neither.

Please help.

**menu_email.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="il.co.talkie.q.SettingsEmailActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:title="@string/save_action"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_err_email"
    android:title="@string/email_err_prompt"
    android:visible="true"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_header"
    >
</item>

</menu>
```

**menu_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="@color/simple_blue">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="@string/service_providers_menu_header"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:editable="false"
    android:inputType="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the relevant code from the activity

**Java code**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_email, menu);

    MenuItem email_err_menu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_err_email);

    View v = (View) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(email_err_menu);
...
   return true;
}
```

The object v above is always null

Answer (score 3):

Try `app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_header"` instead of `android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_header"` if you are using support libraries.

Comment: YES. This did it. Thanks a lot